# Phonegap iOS: InAppBrowser opens but clicking on link sometimes does not open the page and event "falls through" to main webView

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm developing an iOS app using phonegap and HTML5.
After launchImage in app, I open InAppBrowser, which opens promptly.
But, tapping on links in it sometimes does not open the desired page and event "falls through" to main webView.

i.e., InAppBrowser is closed on tapping the link.

Please do help me out as I'm stuck with this for the past two days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Put this code in your MainViewController.m before @end tag

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    // Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
    // Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Mohammad. I'm new to Xcode and can't understand the error that it threw after i tried with your code. 
Error is "No visible @interface for 'CDVCommandQueue' declares the selector 'webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType'"... Apologies if I'm asking a very very basic question

Comment: it's ok my friend. can you show me your error message in your xcode?

Comment: Thanks again buddy. 
Error here: 
2014-03-12 15:25:18.910 REB iOS[5474:60b] webView:didFailLoadWithError - -999: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by bypassing the error code. It is a bit of dirty workaround but couldn't help it. In "CDVInAppBrowser.m", modified as below and InAppBrowser loads my url successfully.

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    //By passing error code
    if(error.code == -999)
        return;
    // log fail message, stop spinner, update back/forward
    NSLog(@"webView:didFailLoadWithError - %i: %@", error.code, [error localizedDescription]);

    self.backButton.enabled = theWebView.canGoBack;
    self.forwardButton.enabled = theWebView.canGoForward;
    [self.spinner stopAnimating];

    self.addressLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Load Error", nil);

    [self.navigationDelegate webView:theWebView didFailLoadWithError:error];
}
```